# Angular 2 - how can I throw errors instead of casting to incompatible types

Tags: angular

I would like to throw an error when myMethod(number) is called with a string passed as an argument, without forcing myMethod to perform the check.

```js
constructor {
  myMethod( <number> <any> "65"); //should be a runtime error, but isn't
}

myMethod(n: number) {
  console.log(typeof n); //"string"
  console.log(n + 1); //runtime error
}
```

Because our app retrieves data from a json on the web, sometimes a developer will change a type, and we have to debug the entire data management pipeline with no indication that strings are being passed around disguised as numbers.

I would like it to at least log when a type is cast to an invalid type, without needing to implement this separately for every type of object retrieved from the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All data that cannot be statically typed should be asserted at runtime.

This can be done with boilerplate `if..throw` statements, assertion libraries or instantiating self-validating classes from data transfer objects (JSON).

> sometimes a developer will change a type, and we have to debug the entire data management pipeline with no indication that strings are being passed around disguised as numbers.

This problem is solved with test coverage.

Answer (score -1):

you can throw any error you like with the throw keyword:

```
if (isNaN(n)) {
    throw "Parameter is not a number!";
}
```

docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw

but your best bet when working with web services is always to strongly type things as soon as they're retrieved so that you always know what you're working with.  It's a fair amount of up front effort that always pays dividends.

Comment: Err, `isNaN('1')` returns false. Besides, your answer doesn't really answer the question, which asks about automating these checks.

Comment: it returns false because '1' IS a number and can be validly used or parsed with a simple + or parseInt, why would you throw an error rather than just typing it? doesn't make any sense from any perspective.  And you interpreted the question differently than me, doesn't make me wrong.  He pretty explicitly asked, how do i throw an error after a type check.  Never said anything about "automating"

Comment: No. '1'  is a string. That's what the quotes around the number mean. And he also clearly said, I quote: "without needing to implement this separately for every type of object retrieved from the web".

Comment: JB, I did edit my question to be more specific, this answer was posted prior to that

Comment: @JBNizet '1' is easily and validly parsed to a number. Why would you throw an error rather than just apply +n? From no perspective does any of that make sense. you're being weirdly pedantic on something you know enough to know youre wrong about. Even if you REALLY wanted to throw an error on valid numbers, you could just use typeof n === 'number' instead, doesn't change that this is how you throw errors. The best approach in a js client dealing with a web service is to always parse your data so you know what your dealing with and not make any assumptions about what a web service gives you.

Comment: @bryan60 because if what is received is a string masquerading as a number, despite the TypeScript interface saying that the type of the field is supposed to be a number, it's a clear sign of a design issue, and there'sa good chance that, in some other case, you'll get 'hello' or any other unparseable string instead of '1', so you'd better fail sooner than later.